# DataTables table not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I'm attempting to make use of the DataTables plugin, and when using the example code on https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html as a starting point I'm having difficulty having the table display, if any suggestions could be made where I'm going wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>DataTables Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale-1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.DataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTablesCSS.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<script src="DataTablesJS.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" class="init"></script>

<div id="container" class="width">
<header>
    <h1>Data<span> Tables</span></h1>
</header>

<div id="body">
<section id="content">
    <br>
    <article>
        <h2>DataTables H2</h2>
        </br>
<html>
<body>

<div>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
    </article>

</section>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, let me know if adding in the CSS, or javascript files would be useful.

Comment: Your code is really messy! Put `<script src="DataTablesJS.js"></script>` after all scripts if you initialize the `DataTable` there

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please try using some HTML code validator like: https://validator.w3.org/

It might not be about DataTables.

Use some reasonable IDE (it might be helpful) or command-line validation tool to get quick info on errors.

Comment: validator.w3.org is not fullproof as it doesn't recognise new changes.

Comment: I am fully aware of that. But in that case it might just fit in. I am not sure if you gave it a try - it already screemed about basic stuff, though some noise appeared as well. And please notice word _like_ . Either way doing that in most cases would make @JG20 get the right answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

Include the data tables javascript at the end of the body instead, this way the HTML is generated before the js can search for the table.

Comment: Do try this and upvote and accept if it solves your problem!